# Android Camera : Does it have a unique package name?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-package-managers, android-applicationinfo

I am building an app that auto sorts installed apps and allows the user to launch those apps. I just ran into a small issue with the camera app. When I scan through the installed apps with '**queryIntentActivities**' for '**ResolveInfo**' I get the gallery ResolveInfo twice and both objects are identical. I am wondering if I am missing something obvious or the camera is simply not launch-able from a package name.

If the camera and the gallery share the same package would I still be able to use the package manager to pull the icons and labels for each? I want to avoid using my own drawable as different OEMs make different icons.

I am aware that I can simply launch the camera with a capture image intent but I do not care for the results and I want to launch the camera as a stand alone activity plus using this intent doesn't really solve my issue.

**Update:**

So the **ResolveInfo**'s I am receiving for the camera and gallery aren't exactly the same. They share the same package name but I can pull their respective icons through the **ResolveInfo.loadLabel** and **ResolveInfo.loadIcon** (rather then what I was doing with **ResolveInfo.ApplicationInfo.loadLabel** ... which returned identical labels and icons). However I am still unable to find any way to launch the activities for the camera and gallery separately.

**Update 2.0**

**Problem solved.** I found the unique activity string in the **ResolveInfo.ActivityInfo.name**. Now rather then launching the app with the package name I just launch it with the activity that was listed in that variable.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get the package name of the camera app is pasted below. You can get the package name by refering to cameraInfo.activityInfo.packageName; returned by the function below

```java
public static ResolveInfo  getCameraPackageName(Context context, PackageManager pm) {
    Intent      intent      = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    ResolveInfo cameraInfo  = null;

    List<ResolveInfo> pkgList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    if(pkgList != null && pkgList.size() > 0) {
        cameraInfo = pkgList.get(0);
    }
    return(cameraInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the package manager for camera and gallery are different.

for camera - **com.android.camera**.
for gallery - **com.android.gallery**.

this is the way in which you would differentiate the gallery and camera.

Comment: I investigated further and it seems that this was true for the older phones. Starting with **android 4.1** the camera and gallery were **merged** into the same package. Granted this is for stock android and OEMs might still have their own camera implementation.

Comment: @https ok, but can you provide the name of that package?